# How to match a regex pattern with a string by providing it a starting line no. and ending line no. within which the search should be performed?

Tags: regex, javascript

I am writing a small windows script in javascript/jscript for finding a match for a regexp with a string that i got by manipulating a file.

I know the line number for starting and ending of the search. But I am stuck at this position for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to look at something like this is to not overcomplicate your regular expression - you could make it rather unreadable and confusing, particularly if your regex skills aren't very good.  Simplify things first - split the document into an array of lines, pick out your line and then perform your regular expression.  Running your regular expression on a smaller string in this fashion could prove to be much faster on very large text files.

```
// Assuming file is a FileSystemObject TextStream object:
var lines = file.ReadAll().split("\r\n"); // split based on Windows newline

// Arrays have zero-based indexes, so the line you need is your line number -1
var match = lines[4].match(myRegEx);      // lines[4] is line 5 of the string

// If you need it to span multiple lines, extract and join the lines you need:
var specificLines = lines.splice(4, 6);   // extract the 5th and 6th lines 
specificLines.match(myRegEx);             // don't forget the regex's /m modifier
```

`splice` returns the array items from the starting index upto **and excluding** the ending index.  You can also provide a `limit` parameter to the `split` method to stop splitting after a certain number of matches.  This should improve speed on a large file where the lines you need aren't near the end.

Glossary:

- [splice Method (Array)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkcsy6fe(VS.85).aspx)
- [split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5az126b(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to match all the lines preceding the bit you're interested in, then capture the part you want in a capturing group.  For example, to extract the fourth and fifth lines, you could use this regex:

```
/^(?:.*(?:\r\n|[\r\n])){3}((?:.*(?:\r\n|[\r\n])){2})/
```

The part you want will be available in capturing group #1.